# Why does the C++ copy constructor behave differently when calling its child copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I have the following toy class A and its child B:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a;
    public:
        A():a(1){cout<<"A default constructor..."<<endl;}
        A(int i):a(i){cout<<"A non-default constructor..."<<endl;}
        A(const A &ao){cout<<"A copy constructor..."<<endl; a=ao.a;}
};

class B:public A
{
    private:
       int b;
    public:
       B(int i,int j):A(i),b(j){cout<<"B constructor..."<<endl;}
       //B(const B &bo){cout<<"B copy constructor... "<<endl; b=bo.b;}
       void print(){cout<<endl<<"class B, a: "<<a<<" b: "<<b<<endl<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    B b1(3,8);
    b1.print();
    B b2=b1;
    b2.print();
}
```

I found that if I don't provide a copy constructor for class B, the compiler will synthesize one for me, and that one uses the copy constructor I provided for class A. However, if I do provide a copy constructor for class B, where I don't explicitly call the copy constructor for the base class A (see code), the compiler will call the default CONSTRUCTOR of class A? Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a constructor - any constructor - for a derived class you *can* (and often *must*) explicitly initialize base class subobjects in that constructor's initializer list. If you fail to do that, then the compiler will implicitly call the *default* constructors for those base class subobjects, assuming they are available. This rule applies to absolutely all user-defined constructors.

This is exactly what happened in your case. You forgot to initialize base `A` in `B::B(const B&)`'s constructor, so the default constructor was used for that base. The fact that `B::B(const B&)` is a *copy constructor* makes no difference whatsoever in this case. It works that way, again, consistently for all kinds of user-defined constructors.

Now, if you do not provide a user-defined copy constructor, then the compiler will attempt to provide on implicitly. The implicitly-defined copy constructor will attempt to call copy constructors for all base classes. The language spec just says that compiler-provided copy constructor behaves that way, which is the answer to your "why" question.

Answer (score 9):

This is the standard behavior. It's mostly for consistency: **any** user-defined constructor that doesn't explicitly call a specific base class constructor will call the default one. Why would the copy constructor be different?

Comment: My question is: why my copy constructor, that doesn't explicitly call the base class copy constructor, actually called the default constructor instead of the copy constructor?

Comment: and, why that if I don't provide copy constructor, the synthesized copy constructor called the base copy constructor instead of base default constructor?

Comment: @HailiangZhang because that's how the standard defines it. Are you asking for the motivation behind it? For consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Order of initialization rules apply here. You can only supersede that rule by supplying your own constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What you haven't noticed is that ***member data* is treated the same way as *base-class data***:  It is initialized by copy-construction if the compiler provides the copy constructor, but initialized by default-construction if you write a stubbed copy constructor.

By implementing the copy constructor, you are telling the compiler that **you will decide how members *and base-classes* will be initialized**.  In the absence of additional instructions from you, these will be initialized using the default method.